# How to std::enable_if only if a certain template has a specialization for a given class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enable-if

I have the following template:

```
namespace std {
template<typename Enum>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<Enum>::value, std::ostream&>::type
operator<<(std::ostream& strm, Enum e)
{
    return strm << helper_of<Enum>::to_string(e);
}
}
```

which helps google-test display human-readable diagnostics when comparing hobbits:

```
template <typename T> struct enumclass {}; // generic template

template <typename T>
using helper_of = typename enumclass<T>::helper; // more mnemonic

namespace MiddleEarth {
enum class Hobbit { Bilbo, Frodo, Sam };

struct HobbitHelper{
    std::string to_string(Hobbit H);
    Hobbit from_string(std::string const& s); // Hobbit-forming
};

template <> struct enumclass<Hobbit> {
    using helper = HobbitHelper; // links Hobbit to its helper
}
}
```

The `enable_if` is there to prevent this templated `operator<<` from being applied to any old class (the naive version without enable_if is ambiguous for classes which already have streaming operators, e.g. `std::string`).

However, if there is an enum which doesn't specialize `enumclass`,

```
enum class Wizard { Gandalf, Radagast, Saruman };
const Wizard g = Wizard::Gandalf, s = Wizard::Saruman;
```

then the following fails to compile

```
EXPECT_EQ(g, s);
```

with `error: no type named 'helper' in 'aws::enumclass<Wizard>'` because the compiler tries to apply the templated `operator<<` to Wizard.

Is it possible to construct an `enable_if` that would only apply this operator<< if there is a specialization of `enumclass<Enum>` ? Google-test then would fall back to display the raw bytes of Wizard and it would compile.

Failing that, is it possible to construct an `enable_if` which would only allow types in a certain namespace (e.g. MiddleEarth)? This would solve the problem if Wizard is not in the MiddleEarth namespace. All the enums in MiddleEarth are supposed to have a specialization for `enumclass`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just move the `helper_of` substitution into the template specification itself:

```
template <typename Enum,
          typename Helper = helper_of<Enum>>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& strm, Enum e)
{
    return strm << Helper::to_string(e);
}
```

That way, if the `helper_of` substitution fails (that is, `enumclass` isn't specialized for the given `Enum`), the entire overload will be thrown out due to SFINAE rather than being a hard compile error - since now we're in the *immediate context* of the substitution itself.

Comment: Beautiful. It works even if `Helper` is not used at all (i.e. the return statement is the original `return strm << helper_of<Enum>::to_string(e);` (with helper_of applied again, redundantly).